# Filling a dynamic array with user input in shell scripting

Tags: arrays, shell, user-input, dynamic-arrays

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to create an array of size `n`, where `n` is input by the user during the run time.

```
while [ $i -lt $n ]
do

    echo For person $i enter the name?
    read io
    eval Name[$index]= $io

done
```

When I try to do this, the values are overwritten every time the loop gets the input from user.

For ex: if person 1 is - Tom,if  person 2 is - John. Then when i try to print the names of all person at the end of the script, person 1 name is overwritten with person n th name.(which means, all names are stored in a single variable instead of an array).

Can someone tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: You can get rid of `$index` and `eval`. Simply replace `eval Name[$index]= $io` with `Name=("${Name[@]}" "$io")`.

Answer (score 3):

- You need to increment `i` in the loop so that it eventually exits. This line increments `i` by 1:

  ```
  let i+=1
  ```
- You don't need to use `eval` in `eval Name[$index]= $io`.
- There is no variable named `index` (at least not in your code sample). I assume you meant to use `i` there. (i.e., `Name[$index]` should be `Name[$i]`)

This code works:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

Name=()
i=0

while [ $i -lt 4 ]
do
  echo For person $i enter the name?
  read io
  Name[$i]=${io}
  let i+=1
done

echo names:
for n in "${Name[@]}"
do
  echo $n
done
```

Comment: Thanks @tony19.It worked for me.I am trying to print multiple array values inside the same loop, for example: person: 1 -  print name,age, dob,etc ..so i followed the same technique of declaring 3 arrays. When i tried to do  " echo person 1 {$Name[$i]}" , i am not able to access the corresponding value of the variable Name. rather it just prints "Name[0]" . Is there any syntax for this case?